# Text running off the page?

Tags: line-breaking

When I typeset to LaTex from Scrivener,the text runs off the page. Each paragraph shows up as a single line that runs off the page.  Does anyone know how do I prevent that?  I'm sure there is a super obvious solution to this but I don't know what it is.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a MWE for better clarity?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: If your paragraphs are coming out as a single line then you have used incorrect markup, unless you show what you have done, it is hard to suggest what is wrong with it.